# À petits petons by Luc Bérimont

Tags: poésie

I'm reading a poem by Luc Bérimont, it sounds fun, but also challenging to me as there are many new words and many of them have multiple meanings ...

Based on the help in comments and websites, I came out with the translation below, pls check if it's correct?

I'm not sure as some stanzas seem don't make sense, but it's a playful poem so that could be the author's intention.

The full content of the poem and my translation is as below

> À petits petons  ->  With little feet
> À gros ripatons  ->  With big feet
> À dos du tonton  ->  On the back of the unky
>
> À petit mitron  ->  With small baker
> Petit mirliton  ->  With small reed flute
> À dos du pinson ,  ->  On the back of the chaffinch
>
> À dos du maçon  ->  On the back of the mason
> Sur un limaçon  ->  On a snail
> Un cheval d’arçons  ->  A pommel horse
>
> À petit bidon  ->  With a small belly
> Sur un hérisson  ->  On a hedgehog
> Tout petit bedon  ->  Tiny belly
>
> À petits mouton  ->  With little sheep
> Tout petits boutons  ->  Tiny little buttons
> Petit puceron  ->  small aphid
>
> À petit piton  ->  At small peak
> Mais à gros ronrons  ->  But loudly
> Petit patapon  ->  Little patapon

Comment: La traduction faite par https://www.deepl.com/translator#fr/en/ est valable.

Comment: Ripatons are feet though, not laughs.

Comment: *petit patapon* is singular, so it can't mean *little children*. And [*patapon*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/patapon) doesn't mean *child*, at least not explicitly. (I suppose it might means the sound of a child's footsteps, but that would just be one interpretation of the poem.)

Comment: @PeterShor Actually I didn't find [word *patapon* at WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/patapon), but this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patapon) says -- Patapon is a 2007 video game... The name Patapon was created by Rolito and was inspired by *an old French word for "children"* -- so I translate it into "children". Any better suggestion pls?

Comment: *[Petons](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/peton)* means small feet a colloquial way. *Bidon* is slang/baby talk for belly (just like *bedon*). *Patapon* has no explicit meaning, it's just a rhyming word, like "alligator" in "see you later alligator" (unlike alligator, *patapon* was "invented" for the purpose and appears in several songs from the 18th century and likely earlier too.)

Comment: If you're going to answer, you might as well do that below instead of in your own question. For _patapon_ see for instance this well known song: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Il_%C3%A9tait_une_berg%C3%A8re It's most likely the sound of a subtle footstep, like a cat's, or a regional adverb for "tout doucement" (DHLF), but this poem etc. is really about how this rhymes more than anything...

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle I’m not confident to call my understanding as an *answer* …

Comment: @jlliagre thank you, i've updated.

Comment: *Tonton* is kiddie speak too and possibly better translated to "unky" or something similar.